# How to insert Unicode U+2665 in a <h2> HTML?

Tags: html, unicode

I wanna insert unicode U+2665 in heading of HTML. Thus, I did:

```html
        <h2 id="listas">U+2665 listas</h2>
```

Unfortunately, this generates the following output when rendered by the browser:

[image]

I tried using "and percent" with `&U+2665`. But it did not work out either.

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter any Unicode character using it's hex scalar value in a character entity reference

```
<h2 id="listas">&#x2665;</h2>
```

That will display as ♥

The other answers were similar, but require converting the Unicode scalar value to decimal. But you can enter it directly in hex.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h2>&#9829;</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like that:

```
<h2 id="listas">&#9829; listas</h2>
```

You can check the HTML entity in pages like this one
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2665

Preview:
https://jsfiddle.net/0mne9kL1/